# How to set value to select box by jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a select box filled by getJson. I need to select option by some hidden element's value:

```
  var dropdown = jQuery('#sport');

  var sport = jQuery('#sport_id').val();

  // Populate dropdown with sports
  jQuery.getJSON("/races/index/sportsjson", function (data) {
      jQuery.each(data, function (key, entry) {
        var selected = false;
        if (entry.key == sport) {
          selected = true;        
        }
        dropdown.append(jQuery('<option></option>').attr('selected', selected).attr('value', entry.key).text(entry.value));
      })      
  });             
  jQuery('#sport').val(sport);
```

The selected option is correct in the select box, but then I want to use the value of the selected option for another function, but if I alert this `jQuery('#sport').val()` , it is empty. But `alert(sport)` returns the value correctly. Where is the problem? I call the next function after the row `jQuery('#sport').val(sport);`

Comment: Where are you trying to alert the value? Remember the ajax call is asynchronous which means it may take some time to get fetch the data. This means that if you are trying to read the value outside the getJson() call then it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: I'm trying it after the row `jQuery('#sport').val(sport);` how can I alert the value correctly- I mean the when is it really set?

Comment: Yeah that is too early. You have to do it inside the getJson() method right after the .each() loop.

Comment: ok, I uderstand, but I need to call another function using the selected value of this select box. How can I do that - to be sure the value is set?

Comment: maybe should I use some callback function? I think so, but not sure how... I'm not FE developer. Is there anybody to help me, please? I need to call next function using  `jQuery('#sport').val()` but it is not set yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax calls are asychronous by nature and the way to pass data after loaded through an ajax call( just like jquery's getJSON) is by chaining a .done() method after your ajax call. 
Inside .done() specify what you would like to do with your fetched data.
Read more on the topic on the official documentation of jquery which is quite straightforward i should add.
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 0):

You have to move all your code inside the getJSON() method so it is executed after the data has been returned.

```
var dropdown = jQuery('#sport');
var sport = jQuery('#sport_id').val();

// Populate dropdown with sports
jQuery.getJSON("/races/index/sportsjson", function (data) {
    jQuery.each(data, function (key, entry) {
      var selected = false;
      if (entry.key == sport) {
        selected = true;        
      }
      dropdown.append(jQuery('<option></option>').attr('selected', selected).attr('value', entry.key).text(entry.value));
    });

    jQuery('#sport').val(sport);//this line is unnecessary because you have already set the selected value above      

    alert(jQuery('#sport').val());
    //Call your xyz() function here.
});
```